# Server 2016 login issue

Tags: login, windows-server-2016

I have a strange issue occurring with a Windows Server 2016 Standard.
Usual DC roles, DNS, DHCP, AD
When trying to log into the console, as soon as your press control/alt/del combo, screen goes sky blue like it is trying to log in but immediately returns to initial screen. Happens in safe mode and DSRM as well.
RDP into the server using Remote Desktop and supplying the credentials looks like it is working but then exhibits the same behaviour. (Screen flashes light blue, then goes black and the session is disconnected).
OTher remote features seem ok, I can remotely control using powershell, and remote registry but trying to get event viewer remotely throws rpc errors.

I have checked system event viewer through powershell but cannot see anything obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: remote event viewer is now ok

Answer (score 0):

Situation is now resolved. SFC /scannow initially found nothing wrong (using ps-remoteing) second run found faults, fixed them and am now able to log back into console